# Type of object with only camel case keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to write a type or an interface that forces the object keys to be in camelCase?

```
type CamelCaseObject = // ... ?

const myObject: CamelCaseObject;
myObject.camelCaseKey; // Ok
myObject.not_camel_case_key; // Not ok.
```

Or an interface would be fine too.

```
interface ICamelCaseObject = {
  [key: string /* that matches camelCase */]: OtherType;
}

const myObject: ICamelCaseObject;
myObject.camelCaseKey; // Ok
myObject.not_camel_case_key; // Not ok.
```

Comment: sounds like a linter responsibility to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't exactly enforce that the string is camel case using static types.  However, you can force all property names to not include underscores which would disallow snake case:

```
type OtherType = string;

interface ICamelCaseObject {
    [key: string /* that matches camelCase */]: OtherType;
    [K: `${string}_${string}`]: never; // matches snake case and forces never
}

// this works
const foo: ICamelCaseObject = {
    heyYou: "boi",
};

// this fails
const foo2: ICamelCaseObject = {
    oh_noes: "hey", // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
};
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8sAWEBOAVc0C8UDOwkEsA7AcwG4BYAKCqOGQDMBDAY2gEkBhRgWwgBsu2CDABGAKwjNgUAN5UoCqAG0A1hBAAuHHiLEoAegBUUBI2nczzRNijMe-QdEP6AulriJU6CpUXKA0loABgAkMrgEJAC+APphEbpRQW5QhBAAbsikBvpQFsBWEDbYhIxqtoxCUIyEACZQ9AD2SKw2aZlIVFFUVPq5CPg2AO7NKthUzI2EuA2NjVqc9gKVwuKS0lhyvoqIIACajQCuWgBEIo34JwA0XT69-fCDDYz4fOOUk9PSTY0ATAtcXjLISiCRSKCbeSKRrwGKERpFU67a45KBoSBQADkCRImKgT3h0kq2HwxFKIj40GAjRM6Cx7WQmIAdLcgA)